# Can GCC create position independent code for freestanding environments?

Tags: c, gcc, freestanding

I have always thought that the generation of position independent code (PIC) basically only depended on the CPU one is compiling for. However, after reading this in the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html):

> For the 386, GCC supports PIC for System V but not for the Sun 386i.

(stating that the ability to create PIC depends on the operating system), I wondered:

**Can GCC create position independent code for freestanding environments, when no operating system is present?**

Comment: yes. gcc cross compilers for embedded systems will create PIC. The 20 year old version of Solaris that ran on the 386i might not have supported PIC.

Comment: Relevant info is [here](http://www.sonic.net/~coad/sun386i-FAQ). In short, gcc was not able to produce PIC code usable on the 386i with native tools such as assembler, linker and dynamic loader. GCC can generate PIC code for an OS-less environment if you take responsibility to load it to the target computer.

Comment: So 386i is a different kind of computer? Then in my eyes, the documentation suffers from a bad choice of words.

Comment: No, it's not. It's a different kind of OS.

Comment: Then why does the FAQ say "The only OS that runs on the 386i is Sun OS"?